# Encrypting field with deterministic vs enabling Field History

Tags: encryption, history-tracking, platform-encryption

I am seeing some inconsistencies with encryption enablement.  For example: Contact.name.  When I enable deterministic encryption, I have no issues.  However, when I enable Field history tracking, I get an apex class error:   line 537, column 33: field 'FirstName' can not be filtered in a query call. I have this enabled: 
**Encrypt Field History and Feed Tracking Values**
*Includes field history and feed tracking changes in data encrypted during the synchronization process*

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Is it because the field history is encrypted with probabilistic?  I assumed if I had an issue, I would have it with both the encryption of the field, and the field history enablement.   Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: TO add sme clarification.  It looks like its only affecting compound fields.

Comment: What's the query you're trying to call that throws the error?

Comment: Hi @KrisGoncalves.  No query throws an error.  I get an email with those apex errors mentioned when I enable field history tracking for those fields.

Comment: Sorry, I meant is it possible to see the lines of code the error is referring to?